# Can I put trainings from my university on my resumé under "Course"?

Tags: resume, education, germany

I am currently in my graduation and will finish my master's degree this summer.

I am able to participate in courses offered by the "career center" of my university. These courses are for every student (and alumni) of my university and I am able to take up to two of them to my master's. These courses are done by external experts paid by the university (We're not charged any additional fee) and we're given certificates (by the university) afterwards.

May I put them on my resumé under "Course"? <sup>(1)</sup> They will be listed on my master's transcript of records anyway but I would ove to add them on the resumé two. I think that will look very good and otherwise I would have only two than four.

I ask, because I am unsure if it's okay to repeat them (because they count already to my master's degree). On the other hand, if I did them as an alumni I would add them definitly.

<sup>(1): is "Course" the right translation? I mean additional training in courses about specific topics in a couple of days outside of day-to-day work.</sup>

Comment: Will they look any different on your transcripts than other courses? Are they some sort of pass/fail or do they use the same grading system. If it's just a way of defining them by your university, nobody is going to really know what that means, but you just want to avoid any discrepancies between what is on your resume and what your transcripts say.

Comment: @JeffO You can pass the courses by attending and participating. There's no test and, of course, I would cleary state how the course name's and that there have been done at the university.

Answer (score 3):

You can add anything to your resume that you think is relevant.

Looking at the new college hire resumes on my desk (Software Developer candidates), most of them have a *Projects* section and one has *Related Courses*. My own resume when I graduated had a similar section.

As a hiring manager, that stuff is a jumping off point for conversation and an indication of what the candidate thinks is interesting and/or important. It's never going to make or break the candidate on its own.

Comment: I was also going to say something similar, along the lines of Related Courses. I don't believe there is any issue having duplicates since your resume showcases your skills and experience, while the transcript will prove that you attended classes.

Comment: @curt1893 generally, I don't get a candidate's transcript. HR will often review them to ensure they meet GPA requirements or to see where the low grades came from (D in "German Literature" is much less relevant than D in "Data Structures and Algorithms"). If you want to call something out to people who will interview you, put it in the resume.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't list them as courses.  On my resume I have a section for skills and experience. If you're getting some sort of certificate for completing the class you can list that, otherwise I would just list it as a skill that you know.